# How can I rotate the image in css when it is outside of ul li list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It seems very easy for others but I can't figure it out. I want to rotate the image which is outside of `ul` list when hover on `li > a`. Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="container">               
     <ul id="mylist" data-angle="all">
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">A</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">B</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">C</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">D</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">E</a></li>
     </ul>
     <a href="#link" class="button">
          <img src="~/assets/logo/compass.png" />
     </a>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="container">               
                <ul id="mylist" data-angle="all">
                    <li class="item"><a href="#home">A</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="#home">B</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="#home">C</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="#home">D</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="#home">E</a></li>
                </ul>

                    <img src="~/assets/logo/compass.png" />

            </div>

Comment: This will be tricky without JavaScript. As a matter of fact, I don't think it can be done without JS.. Are you open to JS answers?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, thanks for your confirmation. If you have any JS answer, can you please share so I can have a look. Thank you

Comment: No worries - check my answer below..

Comment: Can you post the css as well and create a fiddle? I think it is possible with just css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JS solution. As mentioned in my comments, since the image is outside of the list, and the anchor elements you're hovering over within that list aren't siblings or parents of the image of course, I do not think it's possible to target the image based on the hovering of the anchor elements in your markup with just pure CSS.

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  var btnImg = document.getElementById("rotateImg");
  els[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    btnImg.className += " rotate";
  }, false);
  els[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    btnImg.classList.remove("rotate");
  }, false);
}
```

```css
#rotateImg {
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}
#rotateImg.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">               
     <ul id="mylist" data-angle="all">
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">A</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">B</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">C</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">D</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">E</a></li>
     </ul>
     <a href="#link" class="button">
          <img id="rotateImg" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRs5uw4irxGko9F06bx4-M7T8eka0R0PK79NAj2rigANKGhQs_BGwAvZg0" />
     </a>
</div>
```

The above JS loops through each instance of an anchor element within each list item and adds event listeners to each (hover and no hover). If a user hovers over an anchor element, the image which is outside the list rotates 180 degrees. Once the user moves their mouse away from the anchor element, the class is removed.

Comment: Hi David, this is perfect. Thank you so much for your help. works great.

Comment: Downvote? Please let me know where I've gone wrong as I'm happy to be corrected.

Comment: Hi David, I did not downvote your answer as I was saying in my previous comment that your answer is perfect.

Comment: @Flex No worries - glad to help!

Comment: I cannot event upvote your answer as it giving me error saying... "Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the public displayed. Sorry I really don't know what happen."

Comment: @Flex No worries - feel free to return and upvote when you get the rep :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to target that image in `css` however with `jQuery` you can do it as follows:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#mylist li a').hover(function() {
    $('#rotateImg').toggleClass('rotate');
  });
});
```

```css
#rotateImg {
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
}

.rotate {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">               
     <ul id="mylist" data-angle="all">
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">A</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">B</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">C</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">D</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#home">E</a></li>
     </ul>
     <a href="#link" class="button">
          <img id="rotateImg" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRs5uw4irxGko9F06bx4-M7T8eka0R0PK79NAj2rigANKGhQs_BGwAvZg0" />
     </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS :

```
li > a:hover a > img {transform: rotate(7deg);}
```

When you are hover your `a` that is inside `li` your image will rotate

Comment: My bad this only works if the element is insite the same parent. The JS solution of @davidWilkinson is perfect for your project. Good luck with your website :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Rotate image</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 .rotate
 {
  transform:rotate(90deg);
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" height="200px" width="200px">
 </div>

 <div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" class="rotate" height="200px" width="200px">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Rotate image</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 .rotate
 {
  transform:rotate(90deg);
 }
       .images
        {
                margin-top:10px;
        }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="images">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" height="70px" width="70px">
 </div>

 <div class="images">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" class="rotate" height="70px" width="70px">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script, rotate an image after hovering one `a` elements.

How does it work:

- find all `a` elements within `li`
- add to each `a` element an event listener `mouseover`
- when `mouseover` is fired
- get image to be rotated
- apply css rotation on image so it will appear rotated

```js
var rotateImage = function() {
  // rotate image adding css
  var img = document.getElementById('img');
  img.classList.add('rotate');
};
// find out all a elements
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('li > a');
for (var i = 0, len = elms.length; i < len; i++) {
  var elm = elms[i];
  elm.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    // listen to mouseover on each a element, if fired rotate image
    rotateImage();
  }.bind(this))
}
```

```css
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="mylist" data-angle="all">
    <li class="item"><a href="#home">A</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#home">B</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#home">C</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#home">D</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#home">E</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#link" class="button">
    <img id="img" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=150&h=150" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with JQuery solution maybe with combination with green sock animation platform, which has great browser support and it is fairly easy to use for some animation.

```js
var $box = $('.item a'),
  $image = $('#image');

$box.hover(
  function() {
    TweenLite.to($image, 1, {
      rotation: 360
    });
  },
  function() {
    TweenLite.to($image, 1, {
      rotation: 0
    });
  }
);
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.5/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
   
<div class="container">
  <ul id="mylist" data-angle="all">
    <li class="item"><a href="#home">A</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#home">B</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#home">C</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#home">D</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#home">E</a></li>
  </ul>
  <img id="image" src="~/assets/logo/compass.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Rotate image</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 .rotate
 {
  transform:rotate(90deg);
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <img src="Penguins.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
 </div>

 <div>
  <img src="Penguins.jpg" class="rotate" height="200px" width="200px">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```